# VLC - YouTube videos won't play anymore

Tags: vlc, youtube

I would like to play youtube videos on VLC.
I am newbie (one of mac os re, but can fallow instructions :)
when i enter address on network stream nothing happens it is on the playlist but nothing happens it is not playing.
I have a firewall if it helps :)

Problem solved thanks to your help!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I assume you entered the URL correctly (no https but http, and only the v=... part, like `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wxawmjnRWY`)?

Open the Extras menu and click on Messages. Now click play again and see what message's there.

My guess is it's

```
lua error: Couldn't extract youtube video URL, please check for updates to this script
```

VLC parses YouTube's HTML source code to look for the video, but sometimes, YouTube changes its way it outputs the HTML, so VLC is unable to find the video URL.

**Possible workarounds**

- Go to https://www.youtube.com/html5 and enable html5 there to play the video in your browser without flash
- Install `minitube` and try to play the video there
- Wait for an update of VLC (or update the lua script yourself - not so easy, see **Updating the VLC YouTube parser**)
- Install the package `youtube-dl` and download the video to your harddisk. It's a command line utility though

**Updating the VLC YouTube parser**

Update just the Lua script for YouTube parsing to the latest version from VLC:

Open the Terminal application and enter these commands:

Make sure `curl` is installed, we need this to download the new file

```
sudo apt-get install curl
```

Get rid of the old, non-working scripts

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.*
```

Download the current ones (use the whole command line, yes, it's quite long):

```
sudo curl "http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob_plain;f=share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua;hb=HEAD" -o /usr/lib/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.lua
```

See if it works.

Comment: Here's the bug report:  https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/7471

Comment: According to the bug reporter, here's a github for the patched lua script:  https://gist.github.com/3729932

Comment: We need more infos. Open in VLC: "Extras" > "Messages", with that open, enter the youtube url for the network stream, hit play and see if any messages appeared, and tell us about it :D

Comment: sorry for the late reply, despite my efforts the problem remains: 1. the VLC message is exactly the one you have guest Couldn't extract youtube video URL, please check for updates to this script. 2. i really need to be able to play it in some kind of player and not browser :/ 3. I have tried minitube but i doesnt work also it shows this in terminal Error: "/var/tmp/kdecache-izdininkas" is owned by uid 1000 instead of uid 0. i have tried to google it but i can hardly understant what the problem is about 4. i have tired youtube-dl but i get ERROR: unable to download video.

Comment: I've updated my post, see "Updating the VLC YouTube parser". I was able to play videos with VLC after this.

Comment: and one more thank you :) and i haven't copied! Everything worked! :) Good guy phoibos: SEES A PROBLEM - SOLVES IT! ̃

Comment: For a second I thought [I was boned](http://xkcd.com/1316/), but that last suggestion actually worked! So +1 for you, and I'm totally bookmarking this for the next time this happens.

Comment: Thanks, i had this problem on the latest VLC in ubuntu 14.04, some videos would play and some wouldn't, updating the parser solved it.

Comment: On ubuntu linux using version 2.6-6 I had to copy the downloaded youtube.lua file to `~/.local/share/vlc/lua/youtube.lua` and also  `~/.local/share/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.lua` it seems the installation is slightly different. https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/share/lua/README.txt

Comment: 1. In my case with 18.04 the output was to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.lua` (just a `youtube.luac` before there). 2. Didn't work with error _ts demux error: libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS duplicate (received 0, expected 1) for PID 0_ (with somes _adaptive demux: Encountered discontinuity_ before). They are moving all to GitLab [here](https://code.videolan.org/).

Comment: on ubuntu 14.04 works fine, 8 years after !

Comment: I confirm that on Ubuntu 18.04, `cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/playlist/; sudo rm youtube.luac; sudo curl "http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob_plain;f=share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua;hb=HEAD" -o youtube.lua` solves the issue.

Comment: On Linux Mint 20.2 (Uma) with VLC 3.0.9.2 (Vetinari),  like Pablo, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.lua` was the output location .  But it did work for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can run the latest Lua script for extracting YouTube streams
by downloading the appropriate file into your home directory.
There's no need to delete or modify system-level files.
This works just fine:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/playlist/
curl 'https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/raw/master/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua' -o ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.lua
```

or with wget:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/playlist/
wget -q -O - 'https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/raw/master/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua' > ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.lua
```

VLC will use local scripts instead of the system level Lua file here:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.luac
```

By using a local file in your home directory, you don't have to worry about the file being overwritten when the VLC package is upgraded with `apt upgrade` or similar.

Relevant links:

- [youtube parser not updating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250322/youtube-parser-not-updating)
- [Is there any video player that plays Youtube playlists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/199506/is-there-any-video-player-that-plays-youtube-playlists)
- https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/blob/master/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua
- https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/blob/a51ba24aa6b9d5e8864cd6420357091fbd663ed1/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua
- https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Building_Lua_Playlist_Scripts/

Comment: Thank you so much! 2021 working like wonders! <3