# Cannot play youtube videos in SMPlayer (v.0.8.0) using smtube (v.1.1)

Tags: lubuntu, 12.10, youtube, smplayer

Everything seems ok in smplayer except that. Youtube also works in internet browsers.
[image]

Changing smtube settings doesn't help

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is fixed in smplayer 0.8.1 and smtube 1.2. You can get packages from this ppa: 
https://launchpad.net/~rvm/+archive/smplayer

Answer (score 3):

YouTube changed the way it outputs HTML, so SMPlayer can't retrieve the videos URL anymore (it's the same problem for VLC, see [my answer for this here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197739/vlc-youtube-videos-wont-play-anymore/197766#197766))

Until an updated SMPLayer is released, [it appears the only way is compiling the newest version yourself](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5613), since, unlike in VLC, the video retrieval method is hardcoded in C++.