# how to play flash videos in a browser using mplayer or vlc

Tags: flash, vlc, youtube, mplayer

Give the excessive use of CPU while playing flash videos, I am interested in using mplayer or vlc instead. I tried the greasemonkey script with [this](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/24999) userscript in Firefox and Chrome, but it kept saying the scripts are pretty old and needs updating.

Also, I tried a workaround from [webupda8.org](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/2-ways-of-playing-youtube-videos.html) but did not work either.

Anyone has a better / updated script or solution? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try [this one](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/play-youtube-videos-without-flash-from.html). Works for me. Still, far from ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to abandon flash you might be interested in

```
yt-download
```

which you can use to download videos from youtube (and some other sites) and watch them using any player you choose.

There was an add-on for Firefox some while ago wich automaticly replaced the flash-video by a native player and add some controlls but it was abandoned. It might still work but that is not for sure

The original thread by the author:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1487327

Or you could use this script: 
https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/87011

Comment: This is what I get when I install the script 
"The video should be loading. If it doesn't load, make sure a video plugin is installed. If you think it's a script issue, please report it here."

Comment: You need to install browser-plugin-vlc and/or totem-mozilla

Comment: totem-mozilla is already installed.

Comment: Have you tried installing browser-plugin-vlc? Did it help?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly play Youtube videos from VLC media player. In VLC menu, go to *Media > Open Network Stream* and enter the video URL.
[image: Youtube Video]
If you get a *lua error* , you need to update your VLC's youtube parser as explained in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/197766/58990).

Answer (score 1):

This is a topic with which I have been deeply interested myself. I am a performance enthusiast / efficient computing kinda guy. I specialize in optimizing software to suit hardware.
One app of a particular lightweight dist I've taken a love to is a GTk-based youtube browser. Featured in ANTIX Linux. It is more or less a single-paged superquick youtube.com meta searcher - which itself inturn launches MPLAYER at the request of any listed video.

This entire setup intrigued me as it got me thinking about the bit of code the programmer(s) used to get their GTK youtube searcher to pass an URL/steaming media to mplayer.

In that line of investigation, I stumbled across this::
http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1405/stream-youtube-url-directly-to-mplayer.

And there, voila, a bit code resembling that which likely was used with this youtube-browser app that comes in Antix Linux (Great distro).