# Open browser videos (Flash) in mplayer/VLC [2019 Edition]

Tags: video, flash, performance, browser

I know this has been asked before ([how to play flash videos in a browser using mplayer or vlc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220371/how-to-play-flash-videos-in-a-browser-using-mplayer-or-vlc?r=SearchResults)), but those answers are from 2012.

For several years it was possible to just look at the files in `/tmp/'pidof plugin-container'/` while opening the video's website in Firefox. One of them was the video and could be played with mplayer. One of those always was the video.