# changing youtube 720p 480p 1080p settings in vlc

Tags: vlc, youtube

I can watch youtube videos using vlc and the lua file

[VLC - YouTube videos won't play anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197739/vlc-youtube-videos-wont-play-anymore/1325442)

You can run the latest Lua script for extracting YouTube streams by downloading the appropriate file into your home directory. There's no need to delete or modify system-level files. This works just fine:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/playlist/
curl 'https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/raw/master/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua' -o ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.lua
```

or with wget:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/playlist/
wget -q -O - 'https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/raw/master/share/lua/playlist/youtube.lua' > ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/playlist/youtube.lua
```

**But how can I change the video settings from 720p to 480p or 1080p.**

Comment: [Quick link to a relevant 2017 videolan forums post](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=141179). Not vetted or tested, but it might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

It's under Tools - Preferences

Here's an image of it

[image: img1]